# Strange margin with wrap fig

Tags: margins, wrapfigure

this is the result of my code, but I don't undersea why there is so much white....

[image]

This is my code:

```
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{Figures/fig1}
\caption{4-connected grid map.}
\label{4_connected}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{Figures/fig2}
\caption{8-connected grid map.}
\label{8_connected}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
```

Do you have any advise to solve it?

Comment: The `wrapfigure` environment has an optional first argument which is meant for the number of lines of text to wrap around. Please have a look into the documentation of `wrapfig` package. And please post compilable examples, not only fragments of code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added the number of narrow rows, but nothing change..

Comment: Please make your code compilable, add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.
Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[First Img.]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{Figures/first}}\\
\subfloat[Second Img.]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{Figures/sec}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{It works.}
\label{wrap_fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
```